# How to use AmbientLight in combination with MeshStandardMaterial?

Tags: three.js

I'm currently implementing the new `MeshStandardMaterial` in [ViziCities](https://github.com/vizicities/vizicities/tree/0.2.0) and I've managed to get things looking great, so long as I remove the `AmbientLight` from the scene.

In the scene is a base layer which has a texture map and has `metalness` set to 0 and `roughness` set to 1.

[image]

If I leave the `AmbientLight` in the scene then the mesh that I want to reflect the environment map is not only far too bright, it doesn't reflect anything at all.

[image]

The only way I've been able to keep the `AmbientLight` in the scene and have things look ok is to bump up the `metalness` value to nearer 1, which results in far too much reflection on the base layer.

How can I use `MeshStandardMaterial` with an `AmbientLight` or a `HemisphereLight` (to add a little extra ambient colour to the scene) and not have it blow out the lighting when the environment map is dark?

It's entirely possible that I'm misunderstanding how ambient lighting works, so would appreciate direction on that too :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you use the most recent version of three.js and provide a live link of a _simple_ example to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Actually, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/8201 for a simple testbed from the dev branch.  : - )