# How to use GLTF Loader in three.js? Texture and material displaying as black

Tags: three.js

I'm having issues loading a gltf. The model is able to load successfully but all the textures and materials (already embedded in the .gltf) are completely black. When I view it in the gltfviewer, all the textures and materials show up correctly. I'm new to three.js so if anyone can walk me through using the GLTF loader, I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Do you have any light source in the scene?

Comment: I believe so. If I add a phong material and set color to white, the black changes to white.

Comment: What kind of lights? Can you share the model or a demo? Note that metallic materials may require an environment map. In the gltf viewer (http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) you can adjust direct and ambient light to see the effect.

Comment: thanks for replying. How do I share the model? I have the gltf uploaded on github... Also, its a hemisphere light (I just copied the code off another post); the light should be working though? Since I can see the material when I add a phong material with a white color.

Comment: A link to the GitHub project may be enough. Otherwise, Google Drive, Dropbox, Gist, or some other file link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is essentially the same as [How to use AmbientLight in combination with MeshStandardMaterial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583744/how-to-use-ambientlight-in-combination-with-meshstandardmaterial) — your model has a 100% metallic material, and pure metals do not reflect diffuse (ambient and hemisphere) lights.

Ideally, always add an environment map to PBR models. Another solution is to add non-diffuse/direct lights, such as PointLight or DirectionalLight instances. If you are able to edit the model, reducing its metalness would also work.

For more details, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9228.

Comment: You're actually a life saver! I just changed the metallic factor in blender and now everything works. Thanks so much!!