# Aframe ambient light not work with gltf model

Tags: aframe

I tried a easy aframe demo with glft

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="../../../dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
    <script src="js/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene  >
     <a-entity light="type: ambient; intensity: 0.2"></a-entity>        
<a-entity     
        gltf-model="assets/cow02.glb"
        scale="100 100 100"
         rotation='0 0 0'
         animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 20000"
        position="-2 1 -5"
      > 
      </a-entity>     
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

and now the issue is this ambientlight   `<a-entity light="type: ambient; intensity: 0.2"></a-entity>` not working ,I mean nothing change after add this light.

Comment: check out [this discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/ambient-light-and-gltf-models-not-working-results-in-black-model/7428/2) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344348/how-to-use-gltf-loader-in-three-js-texture-and-material-displaying-as-black/53349297#53349297)

Comment: also a glitch would help :)

Comment: Thank you at first   Here is the  [Glitch](https://glft.glitch.me/) and i add a plane to compare  ，So change the metallic factor in blender  will help ？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how the [gltf-loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js) decides what material to use, but it seems Your models material is simple enough to be interpreted as a [MeshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial). According to the docs - it is not affected by any lights.

Probably if You'd set the metalness, roughness, add a normal map - the loader would use a [MeshStandardMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial) (or any other with those properties - which are affected by lighting).

If you want to change the material using three.js, you could write a component like this:

```js
    // wait until the model is loaded
    this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
      // grab the mesh 
      let model = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
      // find the node with the basic material     
      model.traverse(function(node) {
        // ignore bones and other nodes without any material 
        if (!node.material) return;

        // keep the reference to the old material - we want to dispose it later
        var tmp = node.material
        // substitute the material     
        node.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
           skinning: true, // the original material is using skinning
           map: node.material.map // we want the original texture
        });
        // update and clean up
        node.material.needsUpdate = true;
        tmp.dispose()
      }
    })
```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://stack-62987316.glitch.me/).